# Getting specific number of rows from db using nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

How can I get specific number of records from nhibernate like 10 or 15 at a time instead of all records.
I actually got the answer using criteria.setmaxresults().
But my question is how can I get first 10 records, then next 10 records and then.... next 10.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `SetMaxResults()` in conjunction with `SetFirstResult()`